# Solve $2t^2\ddot{x}+4t\dot{x}-4x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $2t^2\ddot{x}+4t\dot{x}-4x=0$ directly

Comment: @Isham  have edited the description. Irrespective of the equation type I am looking for how to solve this DE.

Comment: @Isham I made a typo when posting. The second derivative should not have been squared.

Comment: @Isham I do not see any answer posted?

Comment: ok thanks for the answer I see it now.

Comment: ..Thats good.....

Comment: I don't know if down voting was the best idea though. I actually learnt something by asking and getting an answer to my question. A downvote might stop others from seeing the solution method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2t^2{x''}+4t{x'}-4x=0$$
Rewrite the equation as:
$${x''}+2\frac {(t{x'}-x)}{t^2}=0$$
$${x''}+2\left (\frac {x}{t} \right )'=0$$
Integrate
$${x'}+2\left (\frac {x}{t} \right )=c_1$$
$$\left ( t^2x \right )'=c_1t^2$$
Integrate again.
$$x(t)=c_1t+\frac {c_2}{t^2}$$